# Statistics not collected on Insert-Select

Tags: sql, database, oracle, optimization

Based on the information [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/online-statistics-gathering-for-bulk-loads-12cr1), I expected the statistics to be automatically collected during an Insert-Select operation on a new table in Oracle. However, I don't see any table-level statistics gathered after an insert-select operation.

I have set the parameter ***_optimizer_gather_stats_on_load*** to *TRUE*.

As per requirement (this only works for new tables), I created a new table. There are no rows prior to insert-select and 500 rows post insert-select operation.

Is there something else I am missing?

Update:
Here's my database version

```
select banner from v$version;
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

Here's my target table getting created :

```
create table test(id number, a number, b number);
```

Here's my insert statement :

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into test select id, a, b from duptab;
```

Here's my parameter value :

```
NAME                                   TYPE       VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- -------
_optimizer_gather_stats_on_load      boolean     TRUE
```

Still no stats gathered :

```
SQL> select NUM_ROWS from user_tables where table_name = 'TEST';

  NUM_ROWS
----------

SQL> select log_mode from v$database;

LOG_MODE
------------
ARCHIVELOG
```

Here' the plan

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | INSERT STATEMENT      |        |    17 |   663 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  LOAD AS SELECT       | TEST   |       |       |        |          |
|   2 |   MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL| DUPTAB |    17 |   663 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: To make the test case fully reproducible, can you replace DUPTAB with something simpler, like maybe `SELECT 1,1,1 FROM DUAL`?

Comment: Perhaps the feature is disabled because the compatibility or optimizer features parameters are not standard. Check: `select * from v$parameter where name in ('optimizer_features_enable', 'compatible');`

Answer (score 2):

First check your database version if it is 12g or higher

Then check this documentation [link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/optimizer-statistics-concepts.html#GUID-3ED2DA31-F61B-4E8F-9166-79FB01392B1D)

**Online Statistics Gathering for Bulk Loads**

> Starting in Oracle Database 12c, the database can gather table statistics automatically during the following types of bulk loads: INSERT INTO ... SELECT into an empty table using a direct path insert, and CREATE TABLE AS SELECT

So if you see no statistics collected and the table was empty before the `INSERT` you most probaly

do not use *direct path insert*  (see `APPEND`  hint)

Here a demonstration with simple data

```
select * from v$version;
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
```

**CREATE TABLE**

```
create table tab as
select rownum id, 'xxx' pad 
from dual connect by level <= 10000;

select NUM_ROWS from user_tables where table_name = 'TAB';

  NUM_ROWS
----------
     10000
```

**DIRECT INSERT**

```
drop table tab;
create table tab
(id number,
pad varchar2(10));


insert /*+ APPEND */ into tab
select rownum id, 'xxx' pad 
from dual connect by level <= 10000;
commit;

select NUM_ROWS from user_tables where table_name = 'TAB';

  NUM_ROWS
----------
     10000
```

**INSERT**

But normal insert produce no statistics collection!

```
drop table tab;
create table tab
(id number,
pad varchar2(10));


insert   into tab
select rownum id, 'xxx' pad 
from dual connect by level <= 10000;
commit;

select NUM_ROWS from user_tables where table_name = 'TAB';

  NUM_ROWS
----------
```

If you think the automatic gathering should occurred but it is not, check the restrictions documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/optimizer-statistics-concepts.html#GUID-CDDB5A54-0991-4E68-A9D7-2305777B608B)

For example the gathering is suppressed, if the *table statistics are locked*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried with /*+ APPEND */ hint and still statistics are still not updated.

Comment: @Darzen There are many reasons why the `APPEND` hint may not work. Can you post the full `INSERT` statement, table definition, and whether database is in archivelog mode? It may also help to run `explain plan for insert ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` The Note section of the explain plan will sometimes explain why a direct path insert was not used.

Comment: @Darzen I added a simple demonstration that you can reporduce

Comment: I have updated more information as suggested by @JonHeller

Comment: @Dazen please check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/tgsql/optimizer-statistics-concepts.html#GUID-CDDB5A54-0991-4E68-A9D7-2305777B608B) the restriction for the gathering. As your execution plan doesn't contain the operation `OPTIMIZER STATISTICS GATHERING` I'd suspect that your table statistics are *locked*. If so, unlock and retry, otherwise check the other restrictions documented.

Comment: Thanks for your help Marmite! But I just can't get this to work. I checked all conditions/locks/preferences as per the link you shared and everything seems to be fine. I think I just have to dig deeper!